# Objective C NSThread and anonymous function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, anonymous-function

Trying to use `NSThread::detachNewThreadSelector` with anonymous function

```
void (^testA)(void) = ^
{
 NSAutoreleasePool *oPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  

 NSLog(@"in threadA",nil);

 [oPool release];  
};

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(testA) toTarget:testA withObject:nil];
```

when I'm trying to run application I got error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[__NSGlobalBlock__ testA])'
```

can anyone give me a hand with that?

Answer (score 2):

To use that `NSThread` API, you mist have an object and a selector. While a block is *technically* an object, it doesn't have any methods that you can invoke. As such, there's nothing you could pass in the `action` parameter that would make this work.

If you want to execute a block asynchronously, there are a couple ways you can do it:

- Use Grand Central Dispatch's `dispatch_async()` function, or one of the appropriate variants.
- Give the block to an `NSBlockOperation`, and hand that off to an `NSOperationQueue`.
- Create a method on an object that takes a block parameter and simply executes it, and then pass *that* object and selector, along with the block, to the `NSThread` API. Don't forget to `-copy` the block first, or you'll probably crash.

Answer (score 1):

It just does not work that way. A selector is the name of a method, and a block is not a method so you can't use a selector to call a block. If you want to execute a block in the background, you can use `NSBlockOperation` or `dispatch_async()`.